# How to avoid server load while keeping a good UX in this case?

Tags: javascript, optimization, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an application that on load makes certain requests to backend to fetch data.

On the other hand, I have a web extension that basically modifies the behaviour of the browser's new tab so that when a user clicks new tab my application opens up. It's a productivity tool and users want this. The web extension is mostly an iframe that opens the application inside.

The problem I have is that every time a user clicks new tab, since the app starts loading in the new tab, a request to fetch the data from backend is made independently of if the user really wants to browse through the application or just navigate anywhere else with the new tab. In other words, 95% of the time the users just click new tab to browse and not to see my app. Obviously, this adds a lot of useless load to my server that I want to control.

What I do now as a temporary solution is to store the data in the localStorage, so that when a user clicks new tab, the data is loaded from the localStorage and can immediately be browsed, while I delay the fetches from backend to 12s. 12s because I figure it's enough time to click new tab, make a google query and navigate away. This reduces the load a lot, but obviously, delays the refetch of data for everyone for 12s.

Since the app can be used from multiple devices, delaying the synch for 12s is quite annoying.

Can you think of a better solution? (Obviously, I have no way to know if the users click newtab to see the app or to browse away, actually, not even they know!! so it's a tough one.)

Of course I already added a button to allow users to manually refetch on demand, but it's not a good solution UX wise.

Another way to minimize the load would be to just add the delay of the fetch to those requests coming from the web extension. But since the web extension is just an html that loads an iframe with the website, which ultimately makes the request, I'm not sure if there's a way to know if the request comes from the web extension at all. Is there?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not open an extension page instead of modifying the new tab page? (chrome.tabs.create)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You mean that when a user clicks new tab I create a new tab containing the app?

Comment: I meant use a "browser_action" to open your app and don't modify new tab behavior at all.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Add_a_button_to_the_toolbar

Comment: ah yeah... that defeats the purpose. Users want it on new tab precisely because they wouldn't remember about it otherwise, it's a productivity tool.